# How to use old (pre-es6) snippets in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing JavaScript using VSCode for a platform that does not support ES6 (or ES5.1 for that matter).

Whenever I use a builtin JavaScript snippet such as the `for` loop, it contains `let` and `const` keywords which are not available in my target JS version.

I do also edit other projects that **do** use the latest and greatest JS spec. So is there a way to make a particular workspaces snippets target an older JS spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the built-in snippets target es6 and cannot be configured to target older versions

You can however [write you own](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) that target older JavaScript versions